# Java - getting and using the integers from an array (0-how ever many the user inputted)

Tags: java, arrays

My program requires an input of as many integers as the user wishes on a SINGLE line. My program must then, take the first integer the user entered decide if it is in the range or not. If NOT output error, If YES then do specified conversion. THEN move to the SECOND integer entered by the user (if there is one).

The way I have tackled this so far is this...

```
    System.out.print("Enter a digit(s). ");

    //Gets input numbers and stores them as a whole string
    //e.g if enters 1 2 3 input will = "1 2 3"
    String input = kbd.nextLine();

    //Splits the input at every space and stores them in an array
    //e.g If input = "1 2 3", numbers {"1", "2", "3"}
    String[] numbersString = input.split(" ");

    //Creates an array the same length as our String array
    //How we will store each number as an integer instead of a string
    int[] numbers = new int[numbersString.length];

    //a loop that goes through the array as a string
    for ( int i = 0; i < numbersString.length; i++ )
    {
        // Turns every value in the numbersString array into an integer 
        // and puts it into the numbers array.
        numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbersString[i]);

    }
```

My problem is that I don't know how to GET the first integer entered and then on to the second and so on... (I DONT UNDERSTAND HOW to access the array of integers ive obtained from the user and manipulate them from 1 - how ever many entered.

Comment: Your code, at least what you have showed us, looks fine to me.  What is the actual problem?

Comment: The code is fine yes, but i need to move on to taking the individual integers in the array and doing things with them?

Answer (score 0):

You access the array in a similar way to how you built it. For example, to print out the array, you can do this:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++ )
{
    System.out.println(numbers[i]);
}
```

Note how the for loop is nearly identical to the last for loop in the code you posted. The only difference is `numbers.length` since you want to iterate over the `numbers` array.

You should also take the time to learn about the enhanced for loop which makes iterating over an array much easier.

Comment: First of all thank you for your reply! Yes i understand that but how do i get that specific integer. For example the first one do what i want with it then on to the second one?

Comment: @NB4 Use an `if` statement. Also, remember that the first element of an array is at index 0.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
for(int number : numbers) //iterates through each number in the array of numbers
{
     if(number > 4 && number < 10) //or whatever range you wanted
     {
         number *= 2; //or whatever conversion you wanted
         System.out.println(number);
     }
}
```

This uses an enhanced for loop as mentioned in comment above. The variable number (singular) is each int in your array of numbers.